# Import one typescript file into another one for browser

Tags: javascript, typescript, browser

How can you use 2+ typescript files in a browser app?

test.ts:

```
export class Test
{    
}
```

main.ts

```
import { Test } from "test";
```

I know that the browser can't handle the import statements natively. Using angular, it will combine all the files into one JavaScript file that works in the browser.

With specifying an outfile, it will compile to one JavaScript file, but will only work with AMD or the system module, which then doesn't work in the browser (says system or define not defined).

To use more than one file seems difficult compared to Java, AS3, C++, C#. I could do it the traditional JS way and have everything in one, enormous file, but had thought it was possible to have more than one file for a browser project using TypeScript (and know it's possible using Angular or Ionic, which build on top of it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't job for compiler, especially `outFile` in tsc has slightly different usage. What you need is `bundler`, make single chunk of javascript file from each individual modules can be loaded into browser. checkout bundlers like `webpack`, `parcel`, `rollup`, etcs and you can get concepts of how does it work.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, it seems a needlessly extra (1 TS file can work with tsc, but 2 ts files, need a module bundler or can't be used), but that seems to be the solution. 

Found a discussion on github on TypeScript, and they said they didn't want to add something to make it just work- that there were plenty of 3rd party solutions that allowed it to work. Seems dumb coming from C++, C#, AS3, Java, ect, but good to know there's a way to use 2 ts files.

Answer (score 0):

Confused as to what the question is, the code to import there looks correct in all but the path name for "test" should be "./test" if its in the same folder structure.

Angular will definitely not combine all the files into one Javascript file that works in the browser that will be your build tool which if you're running the angular seed pretty sure its Webpack.

Comment: The question is- how to get the 2 typescript files to work with the browser(after transpiling to JS). If I transpile main.ts to JS it gives basically the same thing:
import { Test } from "./test";
var test = new Test();
Which the browser complains (because it doesn't know how to do the import statement): "SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at top level of a module"

Comment: Sounds like a misconfigured tsconfig my typescript setup skills are limited but i'm pretty sure you have to specify that you want you're imports transpiled into commonjs modules